# Azure Data Catalogue: Assets and users information box gone, how to add it back?

Tags: azure, metadata, documentation, azure-data-catalog

I'm using Azure Data catalogue to catalogue my data. I had two boxes on the landing portal page for asset numbers and user numbers. This seems to have gone missing over the last week or so from my portal. Does anyone know any way I can add this back in? Is there a setting option?

Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an option for setting this, but I've just checked the Azure Data Catalog that I'm using, and I can see those two boxes. Can you give it another try?

Comment: Thanks @EmreSevinç for the reply, I've now left the organisation I was using it in, it was just strange that when the asset numbers increased that the summary statistics vanished!